# Why does my program crash on start up?

Tags: java, android

I think its due to the OnClickButtonListener. Before, when I would click the button the app would crash, but now that I have added a purpose to the button, or at least tried to, it crashes on startup.

```
public class TimeSelection extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private static Button button_sbm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_selection);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnClickButtonListener()
    {
        button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        button_sbm.setOnClickListener
                (
                        new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {

                                Intent intent = new Intent("amardhebardevelopments.myapplication.UnitedStates");
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }



                );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_time_selection, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add try/catch blocks and see what happens: No errors=no way to tell unless it is really obvious

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Use a debugger, and debug the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

with

```
button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```